# How to disable Logwatch filtering script?

Tags: logs

The default config for http-error logs in Logwatch on a CentOS 5 box (logwatch-7.4.0-1) includes the line:

```
*ApplyhttpDate
```

That wipes out *all* lines, because Apache 2.2 uses StdDate format (e.g. `Fri Sep 21 04:44:55 2012`) not the standard Apache format (e.g. `04/Sep/2012:13:46:40 -0500`).

The HOWTo-Customize-LogWatch file says:

> If an executable script is declared in an /etc/logwatch/conf file,
>     all of the executable script declarations in the corresponding file
>     in /usr/share/logwatch/default.conf or /usr/share/logwatch/dist.conf
>     are ignored.

If I create /etc/logwatch/conf/logfiles/http-error.conf and set

```
*ApplyStdDate
```

then it applies the StdDate filter **after** it has applied HttpDate filtering, rather than instead of.

Other than editing `/usr/share/logwatch/default.conf/logfiles/http-error.conf` (which I've resorted to for now, but shouldn't do because it is provided by an RPM) how am I supposed to disable a filter script in Logwatch?

Comment: Sigh, I am having the same problem with logwatch-7.3.6 on RHEL6. Did you ever get this resolved?

Comment: I'm using CentOS 6 now which only has logwatch-7.3.6 and the http-error.conf no longer seems to be part of the package, so my problem has gone away by itself. I never did find a clean solution that didn't involve editing the RPM packaged file. My http-error reporting is now done by a manually installed file under /etc.